# stretching component using left and right in react native

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-native

I'm trying to stretch my `<View>` component using `left` and `right`

I know how to do it in html and css:

```css
.testing{
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="testing"> 
  Hello there
 </div>
```

but how do I achieve the same result in react native?

**Edit**
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ left: 100,right: 20,height:50,position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: 'orange'}}><Text>hello there</Text></View>
    </View>
  );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
    });
```

Comment: As long as you use `css` the methods will be same

Comment: @Viira I tired that but it doesn't work, I've made an edit to the post let me know if that segment of code works for you

Comment: why are you use `View` inside `View`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it's working for me. Try reinstalling and pasting your code in a new project